# Updating Node & NPM VS Cordova update 5

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I just download the VS Apache Cordova Tools Update 5 and I'm running into problems with Node and NPM. I am using the default blank cordova project for testing.

**Versions**

If I run a gulp check for Node and NPM within my VS Project I get: `Node version = v0.10.31` and  `NPM version = 1.4.9`.  However, I also have installed `Node version = v5.4.1` and `NPM version = 3.3.6`

**Problem**

When I publish using Cordova CLI 5.3.3 I get the following error
[image]
When I change the Cordova CLI to 5.4.1 I get the following error:
[image]

If I change the Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > External Web Tools and add the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs` I get the following warning and an `npm install failed` error.

```
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
```

**Other**

If I select `use global installed version` I get 5.2.0.
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Download location and update info for VS Cordova Tools 5
http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/2016/01/13/annoucing-update-5.html

---------------------------Update 1/15/2015 4:50PMEST--------------------------

Here's the build log when publishing blank cordova project with node = `5.4.1` using `node-v5.4.1-x86.msi`  and NPM = `3.5.3` installed using package.json.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp4, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 5.4.1 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.28
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Installing Cordova tools cordova@5.4.1 for project from npm. This could take a few minutes...
1>  Each package is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.
1>  npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
1>  npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
1>  npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\DBiele\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "cordova@5.4.1" "--loglevel" "warn"
1>  npm ERR! node v5.4.1
1>  npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
1>
1>  npm ERR! Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined
1>  npm ERR!
1>MDAVSCLI : npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
1>  npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
1>
1>  npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
1>  npm ERR!     C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\5.4.1\npm-debug.log
1>  [Error: ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1]
1>  C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\q\q.js:126
1>                      throw e;
1>                      ^
1>
1>MDAVSCLI : error : ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1
1>      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\lib\util.js:655:29)
1>      at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
1>      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
1>      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
```

Here's another build log after removing `NPM 3.5.3` , `clearing cordova cache` and `npm cache clean`

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp4, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 5.4.1 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.28
1>  ------ Package not currently installed globally.
1>  ------ Installing globally from source package. This could take a few minutes...
1>  Each package is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.
1>  npm WARN deprecated npmconf@0.1.16: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
1>  npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"5.4.1","npm":"3.3.6"})
1>  C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-tac-cli -> C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\vs-tac-cli.cmd
1>  > edge@4.0.0 install C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\edge
1>  > node tools/install.js
1>  ***************************************
1>  [Error: The edge module has not been pre-compiled for node.js version v5.4.1. You must build a custom version of edge.node. Please refer to https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge for building instructions.]
1>  ***************************************
1>  Success: platform check for edge.js: node.js ia32 v5.4.1
1>  C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  └─┬ vs-tac@1.0.28
1>    ├── adm-zip@0.4.4
1>    ├─┬ edge@4.0.0
1>    │ ├── edge-cs@0.2.7
1>    │ └── nan@2.2.0
1>    ├─┬ elementtree@0.1.6
1>    │ └── sax@0.3.5
1>    ├─┬ fstream@0.1.28
1>    │ ├── graceful-fs@3.0.8
1>    │ └── inherits@2.0.1
1>    ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
1>    ├── ncp@0.5.1
1>    ├─┬ optimist@0.6.1
1>    │ ├── minimist@0.0.10
1>    │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3
1>    ├─┬ plugman@0.22.4
1>    │ ├─┬ cordova-lib@0.21.6
1>    │ │ ├── bplist-parser@0.0.5
1>    │ │ ├─┬ cordova-js@3.6.2
1>    │ │ │ ├─┬ browserify@3.46.0
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ assert@1.1.1
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └── util@0.10.2
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ browser-pack@2.0.1
1>    │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ combine-source-map@0.3.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── convert-source-map@0.3.4
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── inline-source-map@0.3.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ source-map@0.1.34
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │   └── amdefine@0.1.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ JSONStream@0.6.4
1>    │ │ │ │ │   ├── jsonparse@0.0.5
1>    │ │ │ │ │   └── through@2.2.7
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── browser-resolve@1.2.4
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ browserify-zlib@0.1.4
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └── pako@0.2.3
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ buffer@2.1.13
1>    │ │ │ │ │ ├── base64-js@0.0.7
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └── ieee754@1.1.3
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── builtins@0.0.4
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── commondir@0.0.1
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ concat-stream@1.4.6
1>    │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ readable-stream@1.1.13-1
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── isarray@0.0.1
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ └── string_decoder@0.10.25-1
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └── typedarray@0.0.6
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── console-browserify@1.0.3
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── constants-browserify@0.0.1
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── crypto-browserify@1.0.9
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── deep-equal@0.1.2
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── defined@0.0.0
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ deps-sort@0.1.2
1>    │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ JSONStream@0.6.4
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── jsonparse@0.0.5
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ └── through@2.2.7
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └── minimist@0.0.10
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ derequire@0.8.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │ ├── esprima-fb@3001.1.0-dev-harmony-fb
1>    │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ esrefactor@0.1.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── escope@0.0.16
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── esprima@1.0.4
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ └── estraverse@0.0.4
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └── estraverse@1.5.0
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── domain-browser@1.1.2
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── duplexer@0.1.1
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── events@1.0.1
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ glob@3.2.11
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.3.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ http-browserify@1.3.2
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └── Base64@0.2.1
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── https-browserify@0.0.0
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ insert-module-globals@5.0.1
1>    │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ lexical-scope@1.1.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ astw@1.1.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │   └── esprima-fb@3001.1.0-dev-harmony-fb
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └── process@0.6.0
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ JSONStream@0.7.4
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └── jsonparse@0.0.5
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ module-deps@1.10.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ detective@3.1.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ escodegen@1.1.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── esprima@1.0.4
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── estraverse@1.5.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── esutils@1.0.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ source-map@0.1.34
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ │   └── amdefine@0.1.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ └── esprima-fb@3001.1.0-dev-harmony-fb
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └── minimist@0.0.10
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── os-browserify@0.1.2
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── parents@0.0.2
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── path-browserify@0.0.0
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── punycode@1.2.4
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── querystring-es3@0.2.0
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── resolve@0.6.3
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── shallow-copy@0.0.1
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── shell-quote@0.0.1
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ stream-browserify@0.1.3
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └── process@0.5.2
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── stream-combiner@0.0.4
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── string_decoder@0.0.1
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ subarg@0.0.1
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └── minimist@0.0.10
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ syntax-error@1.1.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └── esprima-fb@3001.1.0-dev-harmony-fb
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ through2@0.4.2
1>    │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ readable-stream@1.0.27-1
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── isarray@0.0.1
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ └── string_decoder@0.10.25-1
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ xtend@2.1.2
1>    │ │ │ │ │   └── object-keys@0.4.0
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ timers-browserify@1.0.1
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └── process@0.5.2
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── tty-browserify@0.0.0
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ umd@2.0.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ rfile@1.0.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── callsite@1.0.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │ │ └── resolve@0.3.1
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ ruglify@1.0.0
1>    │ │ │ │ │   └─┬ uglify-js@2.2.5
1>    │ │ │ │ │     ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
1>    │ │ │ │ │     │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
1>    │ │ │ │ │     └─┬ source-map@0.1.34
1>    │ │ │ │ │       └── amdefine@0.1.0
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── url@0.10.1
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── util@0.10.3
1>    │ │ │ │ └─┬ vm-browserify@0.0.4
1>    │ │ │ │   └── indexof@0.0.1
1>    │ │ │ ├── through@2.3.4
1>    │ │ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.14
1>    │ │ │   ├── async@0.2.10
1>    │ │ │   ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
1>    │ │ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
1>    │ │ │   ├─┬ source-map@0.1.34
1>    │ │ │   │ └── amdefine@0.1.0
1>    │ │ │   └── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
1>    │ │ ├─┬ dep-graph@1.1.0
1>    │ │ │ └── underscore@1.2.1
1>    │ │ ├─┬ elementtree@0.1.5
1>    │ │ │ └── sax@0.3.5
1>    │ │ ├─┬ glob@3.2.11
1>    │ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
1>    │ │ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.3.0
1>    │ │ │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
1>    │ │ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
1>    │ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
1>    │ │ ├─┬ npm@1.3.4
1>    │ │ │ ├── ini@1.1.0
1>    │ │ │ ├─┬ minimatch@0.2.12
1>    │ │ │ │ └── sigmund@1.0.0
1>    │ │ │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
1>    │ │ │ ├── osenv@0.0.3
1>    │ │ │ └─┬ request@2.21.0
1>    │ │ │   ├── aws-sign@0.3.0
1>    │ │ │   ├── cookie-jar@0.3.0
1>    │ │ │   ├─┬ form-data@0.0.8
1>    │ │ │   │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
1>    │ │ │   │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
1>    │ │ │   ├─┬ hawk@0.13.1
1>    │ │ │   │ ├─┬ boom@0.4.2
1>    │ │ │   │ │ └── hoek@0.9.1
1>    │ │ │   │ ├── hoek@0.8.5
1>    │ │ │   │ └─┬ sntp@0.2.4
1>    │ │ │   │   └── hoek@0.9.1
1>    │ │ │   ├─┬ http-signature@0.9.11
1>    │ │ │   │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
1>    │ │ │   │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
1>    │ │ │   │ └── ctype@0.5.2
1>    │ │ │   ├── json-stringify-safe@4.0.0
1>    │ │ │   ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
1>    │ │ │   └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
1>    │ │ ├─┬ npmconf@0.1.16
1>    │ │ │ ├─┬ config-chain@1.1.8
1>    │ │ │ │ └── proto-list@1.2.3
1>    │ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
1>    │ │ │ ├── ini@1.1.0
1>    │ │ │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
1>    │ │ │ ├─┬ nopt@2.2.1
1>    │ │ │ │ └── abbrev@1.0.5
1>    │ │ │ └── once@1.3.0
1>    │ │ ├── osenv@0.0.3
1>    │ │ ├─┬ plist-with-patches@0.5.1
1>    │ │ │ ├── xmlbuilder@0.4.3
1>    │ │ │ └── xmldom@0.1.19
1>    │ │ ├── properties-parser@0.2.3
1>    │ │ ├── q@0.9.7
1>    │ │ ├─┬ rc@0.3.0
1>    │ │ │ ├── deep-extend@0.2.10
1>    │ │ │ ├── ini@1.1.0
1>    │ │ │ └─┬ optimist@0.3.7
1>    │ │ │   └── wordwrap@0.0.2
1>    │ │ ├─┬ request@2.22.0
1>    │ │ │ ├── aws-sign@0.3.0
1>    │ │ │ ├── cookie-jar@0.3.0
1>    │ │ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
1>    │ │ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.0.8
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── async@0.2.10
1>    │ │ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
1>    │ │ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
1>    │ │ │ ├─┬ hawk@0.13.1
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ boom@0.4.2
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └── hoek@0.9.1
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── hoek@0.8.5
1>    │ │ │ │ └─┬ sntp@0.2.4
1>    │ │ │ │   └── hoek@0.9.1
1>    │ │ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
1>    │ │ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
1>    │ │ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@4.0.0
1>    │ │ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
1>    │ │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
1>    │ │ │ ├── qs@0.6.6
1>    │ │ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
1>    │ │ ├── semver@2.0.11
1>    │ │ ├── shelljs@0.1.4
1>    │ │ ├─┬ tar@0.1.19
1>    │ │ │ ├── block-stream@0.0.7
1>    │ │ │ ├─┬ fstream@0.1.27
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── graceful-fs@3.0.2
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
1>    │ │ │ │ └── rimraf@2.2.8
1>    │ │ │ └── inherits@2.0.1
1>    │ │ ├── underscore@1.4.4
1>    │ │ └─┬ xcode@0.6.6
1>    │ │   ├── node-uuid@1.3.3
1>    │ │   └── pegjs@0.6.2
1>    │ ├─┬ nopt@1.0.10
1>    │ │ └── abbrev@1.0.7
1>    │ ├─┬ npm@1.3.4
1>    │ │ ├─┬ cmd-shim@1.1.0
1>    │ │ │ └── graceful-fs@1.2.3
1>    │ │ ├── ini@1.1.0
1>    │ │ ├─┬ minimatch@0.2.12
1>    │ │ │ └── sigmund@1.0.0
1>    │ │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
1>    │ │ ├── osenv@0.0.3
1>    │ │ ├─┬ read-installed@0.2.2
1>    │ │ │ └── graceful-fs@1.2.3
1>    │ │ ├─┬ read-package-json@1.1.0
1>    │ │ │ └── graceful-fs@1.2.3
1>    │ │ ├─┬ request@2.21.0
1>    │ │ │ ├── aws-sign@0.3.0
1>    │ │ │ ├── cookie-jar@0.3.0
1>    │ │ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.0.8
1>    │ │ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
1>    │ │ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
1>    │ │ │ ├─┬ hawk@0.13.1
1>    │ │ │ │ ├─┬ boom@0.4.2
1>    │ │ │ │ │ └── hoek@0.9.1
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── hoek@0.8.5
1>    │ │ │ │ └─┬ sntp@0.2.4
1>    │ │ │ │   └── hoek@0.9.1
1>    │ │ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.9.11
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
1>    │ │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
1>    │ │ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
1>    │ │ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@4.0.0
1>    │ │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
1>    │ │ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
1>    │ │ ├─┬ rimraf@2.2.0
1>    │ │ │ └── graceful-fs@1.2.3
1>    │ │ └─┬ sha@1.0.1
1>    │ │   └── graceful-fs@1.2.3
1>    │ ├── q@0.9.7
1>    │ ├─┬ rc@0.3.0
1>    │ │ ├── deep-extend@0.2.11
1>    │ │ ├── ini@1.1.0
1>    │ │ └── optimist@0.3.7
1>    │ └── underscore@1.4.4
1>    ├── q@1.0.1
1>    ├─┬ request@2.36.0
1>    │ ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
1>    │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
1>    │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.4
1>    │ │ ├── async@0.9.2
1>    │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.7
1>    │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
1>    │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
1>    │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
1>    │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
1>    │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
1>    │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
1>    │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.1
1>    │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
1>    │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.5
1>    │ │ └── ctype@0.5.3
1>    │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1
1>    │ ├── mime@1.2.11
1>    │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.7
1>    │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
1>    │ ├── qs@0.6.6
1>    │ ├── tough-cookie@2.2.1
1>    │ └── tunnel-agent@0.4.2
1>    ├── rimraf@2.2.6
1>    ├─┬ ripple-emulator@0.9.32
1>    │ ├── accounting@0.4.1
1>    │ ├── colors@0.6.0-1
1>    │ ├── connect-xcors@0.5.2
1>    │ ├─┬ express@3.1.0
1>    │ │ ├── buffer-crc32@0.1.1
1>    │ │ ├── commander@0.6.1
1>    │ │ ├─┬ connect@2.7.2
1>    │ │ │ ├── bytes@0.1.0
1>    │ │ │ ├── formidable@1.0.11
1>    │ │ │ ├── pause@0.0.1
1>    │ │ │ └── qs@0.5.1
1>    │ │ ├── cookie@0.0.5
1>    │ │ ├── cookie-signature@0.0.1
1>    │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
1>    │ │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
1>    │ │ ├── fresh@0.1.0
1>    │ │ ├── methods@0.0.1
1>    │ │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.3
1>    │ │ ├── range-parser@0.0.4
1>    │ │ └─┬ send@0.1.0
1>    │ │   └── mime@1.2.6
1>    │ ├── moment@1.7.2
1>    │ ├── open@0.0.3
1>    │ └─┬ request@2.12.0
1>    │   └─┬ form-data@0.0.3
1>    │     └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.3
1>    │       └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
1>    ├── semver@2.3.1
1>    └─┬ tar@0.1.20
1>      └── block-stream@0.0.8
1>  ------ npm install of vs-tac@1.0.28 from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac completed.
1>  ------ Installing Cordova tools cordova@5.4.1 for project from npm. This could take a few minutes...
1>  Each package is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.
1>  npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
1>  npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
1>  npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\DBiele\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "cordova@5.4.1" "--loglevel" "warn"
1>  npm ERR! node v5.4.1
1>  npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
1>
1>  npm ERR! Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined
1>  npm ERR!
1>MDAVSCLI : npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
1>  npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
1>
1>  npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
1>  npm ERR!     C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\5.4.1\npm-debug.log
1>  [Error: ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1]
1>  C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\q\q.js:126
1>                      throw e;
1>                      ^
1>
1>MDAVSCLI : error : ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1
1>      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\lib\util.js:655:29)
1>      at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
1>      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
1>      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

When I use powershell or cmd to install cordova `npm install -g cordova` I get the following error

```
C:\Users\DBiele>npm install -g cordova
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm a
nd is now out of date with respect to npm
npm WARN install:isarray ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\DBi
ele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\buffer\node_modules\is
array' -> 'C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules
\buffer\node_modules\isarray'
npm WARN install:negotiator ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\
DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\express\node_module
s\negotiator' -> 'C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_
modules\express\node_modules\negotiator'
npm WARN install:vary ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\DBiele
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\express\node_modules\vary
' -> 'C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\expr
ess\node_modules\vary'
npm WARN install:object-assign ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Use
rs\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\got\node_modules
\object-assign' -> 'C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\nod
e_modules\got\node_modules\object-assign'
npm WARN install:convert-source-map ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C
:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\insert-modu
le-globals\node_modules\convert-source-map' -> 'C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\insert-module-globals\node_modules\convert
-source-map'
npm WARN install:graceful-fs ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users
\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\write-file-atomic\
node_modules\graceful-fs' -> 'C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\read-package-json\node_modules\graceful-fs'
npm WARN install:deep-extend ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users
\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\registry-url\node_
modules\deep-extend' -> 'C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordov
a\node_modules\registry-url\node_modules\deep-extend'
npm WARN install:strip-json-comments ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '
C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\registry-u
rl\node_modules\strip-json-comments' -> 'C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\cordova\node_modules\registry-url\node_modules\strip-json-comments'
npm WARN install:mime-types ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\
DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\request\node_module
s\mime-types' -> 'C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_
modules\request\node_modules\mime-types'
npm WARN install:qs ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\DBiele\A
ppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\request\node_modules\qs' ->
 'C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\request\
node_modules\qs'
isarray@1.0.0 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\buffer\node_modules\isarray -> n
ode_modules\cordova\node_modules\buffer\node_modules\isarray
negotiator@0.5.3 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\express\node_modules\negotiat
or -> node_modules\cordova\node_modules\express\node_modules\negotiator
accepts@1.2.13 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\express\node_modules\accepts ->
 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\express\node_modules\accepts
vary@1.0.1 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\express\node_modules\vary -> node_m
odules\cordova\node_modules\express\node_modules\vary
object-assign@3.0.0 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\got\node_modules\object-as
sign -> node_modules\cordova\node_modules\got\node_modules\object-assign
convert-source-map@1.1.3 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\insert-module-globals
\node_modules\convert-source-map -> node_modules\cordova\node_modules\insert-mod
ule-globals\node_modules\convert-source-map
graceful-fs@4.1.2 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\write-file-atomic\node_modul
es\graceful-fs -> node_modules\cordova\node_modules\read-package-json\node_modul
es\graceful-fs
deep-extend@0.4.0 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\registry-url\node_modules\de
ep-extend -> node_modules\cordova\node_modules\registry-url\node_modules\deep-ex
tend
strip-json-comments@1.0.4 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\registry-url\node_mo
dules\strip-json-comments -> node_modules\cordova\node_modules\registry-url\node
_modules\strip-json-comments
mime-types@1.0.2 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\request\node_modules\mime-typ
es -> node_modules\cordova\node_modules\request\node_modules\mime-types
qs@2.3.3 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\request\node_modules\qs -> node_modul
es\cordova\node_modules\request\node_modules\qs
readable-stream@1.0.33 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_module
s\request\node_modules\bl\node_modules\readable-stream -> node_modules\cordova\n
ode_modules\browser-pack\node_modules\readable-stream
bl@0.9.4 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\request\node
_modules\bl -> node_modules\cordova\node_modules\bl
request@2.47.0 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\reques
t -> node_modules\cordova\node_modules\request
npmconf@2.1.2 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npmconf
 -> node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npmconf
glob@4.0.6 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\glob -> no
de_modules\cordova\node_modules\glob
tar@1.0.2 node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\tar -> node
_modules\cordova\node_modules\tar
- C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\write-fi
le-atomic node_modules\cordova\node_modules\write-file-atomic
C:\Users\DBiele\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── (empty)

npm ERR! code 1
```

-------------------------------Update 2 1/15/2016------------------------
It now appears to be working!  I used Michael Braude's comment to `npm -g install npm` and it works.

However, before the fix I did the following:

1. removed Node using `add and remove programs`
2. removed NPM by deleting the NPM folder in roaming.
3. Repaired VS2015

After using `npm -g install npm` I updated `node` to `5.4.1 - 64 bit`, I also checked to make sure NPM 3.5.4 worked and used `npm -g install npm@3.5.4` and it worked.

In addition, I changed the sandboxed (I think?) version of Node and NPM by adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs` to Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > External Web Tools [image]

I am now able to run my gulp task using `Task Runner Explorer` without getting errors.  Crossing fingers that it continues to work!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that the version of npm that is bundled with the "latest stable" version of node does not properly install some of our npm packages. To fix this, open a command prompt and run:

```
npm -g install npm
```

To update npm to the latest version. This should fix the problem.

Edit 2/5/2016 - We have release Update 6 which fixes this problem. See our blog for more info: http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/2016/02/04/announcing-update-6.html

(Disclosure: I work on the tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio)

Comment: Thanks for your work - if/when you have the time, appreciate guidance since [Update 6 seems to have broken other things](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35393247/304683)..

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issues with update 6! Update 7 fixes those :) http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/2016/03/01/announcing-update-7.html

Answer (score 7):

Okay I had to do a combination of things to get this working.

First of all vs-tac uses edge v4 which is not compatible with node v5 so you will need to edit the vs-tac package.json file so it refers to v5 rather than v4 (it seems to work for me but your mileage may vary)

Next as Michael Braude mentioned, you will also need this;

```
npm -g install npm
```

Finally you should be able to reinstall vs-tac with this;

```
npm install -g "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\Packages\vs-tac"
```

If the result of this is not an error then double check that the file `vstac_installing.tmp` has been removed from your global node_modules folder (c:\users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules) - I had to manually remove it on my machine.

After all that my hello world project finally runs in the emulator!

Good luck...

Comment: We have fixed this in Update 6. Please see http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/2016/02/04/announcing-update-6.html for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like npm deprecated npmconf but does not automatically remove it as some package might still rely on it. My cordova runs again after uninstalling nmpconf and then updating cordova:

```
npm uninstall -g npmconf
npm install -g cordova
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Unfortunately, when I run `npm install -g cordova` I get an error `npm ERR! cord 1`.  Based on this, I think there's a problem with my node or npm?