# how to install cordova in mac os 10.10.5

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3, ios9.2

all  how install cordova in mac os X Yosemite10.10.5

how to install Cordova in mac os 10.10.5 for developing hybrid application by terminal.

help me 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need Node.js and use
Install

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova
```

create new project

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

more information [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/cli/)

Comment: But i am getting this error                                                                                                   !!!!!         npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793930/updating-node-npm-vs-cordova-update-5

Comment: but i am getting!!!!! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator

Answer (score 0):

check you have installed node js. and which version of node js are using

From terminal chek

```
npm -v
```