# VS 2015 Cordova Tools Update 5 installation issue

Tags: node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I've been reading all the questions regarding this but haven't found something that can be useful on my current issue.

I've downloaded and installed VS TACO Update 5 in my VS 2015 Enterprise. I've got installed Node (4.2.1) and NPM (3.3.12) as well. Now, having all this, when I create a Cordova new project and try to build it something is wrong.

    `1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp1, Configuration: Debug Windows Phone (Universal) ------
    1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 4.2.1 (x64) and npm.
    1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
    1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
    1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.28
    1>  ------ Package not currently installed globally.
    1>  ------ Installing globally from source package. This could take a few minutes...
    1>  Each package is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.
    1>  npm WARN deprecated npmconf@0.1.16: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
    1>  npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"4.2.1","npm":"3.3.12"})
    1>  npm WARN install:rimraf@2.2.0 ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users\jgomezl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf\bin.js'
    1>  npm WARN install:rimraf@2.2.0 ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users\jgomezl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf\bin.js'
    1>  > edge@4.0.0 install C:\Users\jgomezl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\edge
    1>  > node tools/install.js
    1>  Success: platform check for edge.js: node.js x64 v4.2.1
    1>  C:\Users\jgomezl\AppData\Roaming\npm
    1>  └── (empty)
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cmd-shim with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sha with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cmd-shim with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sha with new installed version
    1>  npm ERR! code 1
    1>  ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1
    1>  ------ Package installation failed. Retrying...
    1>  npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"4.2.1","npm":"3.3.12"})
    1>  npm WARN deprecated npmconf@0.1.16: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
    1>  npm WARN install:rimraf@2.2.0 ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users\jgomezl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf\bin.js'
    1>  npm WARN install:rimraf@2.2.0 ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users\jgomezl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf\bin.js'
    1>  > edge@4.0.0 install C:\Users\jgomezl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\edge
    1>  > node tools/install.js
    1>  Success: platform check for edge.js: node.js x64 v4.2.1
    1>  C:\Users\jgomezl\AppData\Roaming\npm
    1>  └── (empty)
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cmd-shim with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sha with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cmd-shim with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf with new installed version
    1>  npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sha with new installed version
    1>  npm ERR! code 1
    1>  ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1
    1>  ------ Package installation failed. Retrying...
    1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(279,5): error : Error installing local npm package.
    1>  module.js:339
    1>      throw err;
    1>      ^
    1>
    1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLD401: Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module 'C:\Users\jgomezl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'. Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.
    1>      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    1>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    1>      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    1>      at startup (node.js:134:18)
    1>      at node.js:961:3
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
    ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========`

I've read something about similar issues caused by incompatible versions of Node (5.x) or NPM (3.X) but I think they were on previous VS TACO releases.

AM I missing something?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34949737/2766725 I lost a lot of time solving this

Comment: I don't know if upgrading npm (I did it) solved this or maybe also reinstalling android SDK and some other stuff helped to that. Anyway, thanks for the hint!

Comment: It's not only upgrade npm. You need to upgrade node, cordova and configure vs-tac package.json with edge in 5.0.0 version and run npm install in vs-tac/pacakge.json