# Cannot compile Ionic Cordova (Update 6) app on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

Recently I updated to Cordova Tools version 6 for Visual Studio I am now getting this error. Anytime I try to build my solution.

```
: BLD00401 : Could not find module 'C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'. Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.
```

I have tried to follow this guide to reinstall vs-tac but no dice.
<strike>https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn771551%20(v=vs.140).aspx#vstac</strike>
http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-vs-tools-apache-cordova/#vstac

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: You're not alone. That's the **exact** same error I have with **(1)** Existing projects (Ionic), **(2)** Even if you create a NEW project - both Blank or Ionic tempate, after installing `Update 6`. REF: http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/2016/02/04/announcing-update-6.html

Comment: So I take it we just have to wait for it to be solved then?  :(

Comment: Haven't managed to figure anything out - the answer below doesn't work for me (tried all of it), but that doesn't mean it won't work for you (seems to work for _some_). I'm on `node v4.3.0` and `npm v3.7.2`

Comment: BTW, do you also get a `Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets` error  (line 279 for me) _"Error installing npm package"_ along with that?

Comment: I just want to clarify, does this only happen on Ionic templates? Or if you make a new regular project does it still repro?

Comment: @MichaelBraude - thanks for your time! Happens to all templates. I _believe_ I found the bug/culprit (at least in my case) - `space` in username e.g. `c:\users\ed chavez` and have it [detailed below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35424151/304683).

Comment: Yes that is the problem. Sorry for the trouble. We'll have a fix in the next release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a bug that we introduced in Update 6 that causes npm install errors if the path to your npm install directory (usually in your AppData folder) has a space in the path.  The simple workaround is to change your npm install directory:

npm config set prefix "C:\Folder\With\No\Spaces"

And then build again in VS.  We will get this fixed up and released in Update 7 as soon as we can.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Installing the package manually will also work: npm install -g "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac"

Comment: Thanks so much for checking in! I will try `npm config set prefix` and report back (am not using affected box right now). I did try the manual install as suggested by @RicardoPontual below, and it didn't do anything for me. Thnx again!

Comment: Many thanks! I'm in a good place (`config set prefix` did it for me) :)

Comment: Note: Update 7 has a fix for this and is released. Please see http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/2016/03/01/announcing-update-7.html for more info.

Comment: Are there any other issues that this would show up I am using VS 2015 update 3 and TACO Update 10 ?

Answer (score 2):

Update: <strike>a possible workaround below</strike> Many thanks to the MS team > <strike>[see answer for fix until Update 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35437236/304683)</strike>

### [Update 7 is/has been released and resolves this issue (spaces in path)](http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/2016/03/01/announcing-update-7.html)

---

Not an answer - more like an "inventory" of attempts at getting to one.

---

### Environment:

- Visual Studio 2015 (all updates)
- Node v4.3.0
- Npm v3.7.2

### Errors

In any Cordova Project - existing, new (blank template, ionic template), etc.

```
BLD401  Error : 
BLD00401 : Could not find module 'C:\Users\Ed Chavez\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'. 
Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.
```

### Attempts

- following the instruction to Clear Cordova Cache and rebuild does not resolve anything
- copying the `vs-tac` (from original `Program Files`) to the folder in the error, does not resolve the issue. Each time you build your project, that copied folder is **cleared/removed**
- following advice to [reinstall `vs-tac`](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-vs-tools-apache-cordova/#vstac) does not resolve the issue
- trying to run repair Cordova Tools (my experiment) does not resolve the issue

### <strike>Possible culprit</strike> This IS the culprit: `space` in path

Inspecting `Output window` points to what could be the issue (detail below):

- at the point where `vs-tac` is being installed:

`'C:\Users\Ed' is not recognized as an internal or external command, (TaskId:10)`

which is the (my) `Users` folder and it contains a `space` between my first and last name.

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 4.3.0 (x64) and npm. (TaskId:10)
------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac (TaskId:10)
------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac (TaskId:10)
------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.34 (TaskId:10)
------ Package not currently installed globally. (TaskId:10)
------ Installing globally from source package. This could take a few minutes... (TaskId:10)
Each package is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies. (TaskId:10)
'C:\Users\Ed' is not recognized as an internal or external command, (TaskId:10)
operable program or batch file. (TaskId:10)
------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1 (TaskId:10)
------ Package installation failed. Retrying... (TaskId:10)
```

So now in search of some fix (likely must come from Microsoft)...will update as necessary

---

### Update: <strike>This is a workaround, NOT a fix</strike> [See above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35437236/304683)

After more tinkering, the issue is the `space` in your **Windows User name**. So if your users folder looks something like this `c\users\firstName lastName\` you will be affected by this bug.

- I created a new (local) user in Windows 10
- username has no spaces *edsf*
- Created a new blank project (vs template)
- Build without a hitch

Here's the portion where `vs-tac` is **successfully** installed, now with a username with no spaces (**edsf**)

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 4.3.0 (x64) and npm.
---skipped for brevity ---

edge-cs@0.3.0 install C:\Users\edsf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\edge\node_modules\edge-cs
...
Success: platform check for edge.js: node.js x64 v4.3.0
C:\Users\edsf\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-tac-cli -> C:\Users\edsf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\vs-tac-cli.cmd
```

Comment: Great. Let me know if you have any issues when installing packages or running the emulator. I'd some some problems with internet access/proxy and I've some notes about how to fix it.

Comment: @RicardoPontual Awesome thanks for all your time and help! Above answer/temp fix from MS worked for me (setting prefix to folder-without-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

I'd the same issue here.
In my computer I'd to copy app.js from another folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\Packages\vs-tac
```

I know this is not a good solution, but worked for me.

But in another computer here, I reinstalled with this command and worked (I closed VS prior to run this command, and started a new project):

```
npm install -g "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac"
```

Hope these notes can help you out.

Comment: Your  first option (copying) was also mentioned in another SO post, but wasn't clear where you **copied to** - I tried copying it to the folder where the error message is pointing to (`AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`) but that didn't do anything. After a `build` that folder is wiped out (kinda makes sense, so there's something else that does what it says - build based on some setting/s) - it's that "something"/"somewhere" that I can't find/figure out at the moment...

Comment: I've copied to the vs-tac folder where error happened: C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac

Comment: Thanks - does it stay there _after_ you `rebuild` any Cordova app?

Comment: @EdSF yes, it does. When I tried to build, some other files was missing (like plugman and optimist), but those I could install running npm install -g [name]. After some tries, I was able to build and the application.

Comment: Got it - thank you for your time! It doesn't do that for me at all. Any rebuild I do removes that (copied vs-tac) folder and error doesn't go way. An additional error that goes with points to some mysterious `line 279` in `Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets` (Error installing local npm package)

Comment: @EdSF There's two vs-tac folders, one is below c:\Program Files (this folder isn't delete) and other below C:\Users. You must install vs-tac in c:\Program Files folder. The app.js file exists in both folders in your computer?

Comment: Correct. only the folder that is _copied_ (into `c:\users\..`) is cleared/deleted after a (re)build. The original (in `c:\program files'`) is not affected. I've added detail after tinkering above (in my "answer"- it's not, but it shows all the detail and a possible source of the problem). Thank you!

Comment: In the process where tooling installs `vs-tac` as shown in the Output Window, it fails (in my case) because my `Users` folder contains a space (my name): `'C:\Users\Ed' is not recognized as an internal or external command, (TaskId:10)`

Comment: @EdSF verifiy if your config path is correct with this command: npm config get userconfig    if your path is wrong (it's truncated because the space) you can set using: npm config set userconfig "[path]\.npmrc"