# What is causing npm install -g cordova ionic Is out of date

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

How i get a error when trying to install cordova and ionic when i try this:  `npm install -g cordova ionic`  i keep getting an error when trying to install This is what i get:

```
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
```

Does this mean that there something wrong with ionic or cordova i don't know what that error message means?

Or is it deprecated what would i use instead if so?

My error is different from all other questions i have looked at the possible duplicate and it did not help there is another problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating Node & NPM VS Cordova update 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793930/updating-node-npm-vs-cordova-update-5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this before installation

```
npm cache clean
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Everybody but i found out my problem but i still got the error but it installed i was using git so i swiched to command prompt and it worked, but i had to do it separately like this:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

And then like this

```
npm install -g ionic
```